# Highlight Files in X and get some function executed, how?

Tags: xorg

Suppose I want to execute

```
pdftk input FilesHighlightedInX out specifiedByUserInX
```

in the following way:

1. User highlights files in X
2. User clicks some button, shortcut, right-mouse-button-select, to execute a Bash script with the `pdftk` command
3. The output file will appear in the directory where the user executed the command (the user can specify the name of the output or not, modular functionality)

How can I do this in X?

Comment: You don't highlight files in X. Try again.

Comment: **[Achievement](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/acme/) [unlocked](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/plumb)[!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_User_Space)**

Comment: @sr_: Plan9 doesn't run X.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: But [plan9port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_User_Space) runs on Linux (amongst others) and includes Acme and Plumber. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you accept *marking a file icon* in a file browser (such as GNOME's Nautilus) as highlighting, ["Nautilus-Actions"](http://www.grumz.net/index.php?q=taxonomy/term/2/9) could be interesting to you:

> Nautilus-Actions is a Nautilus extension whose principal function is to allow the user to **add arbitrary actions to the file manager context menus**. These actions may be organized in menus and submenus, exported and shared with other desktop environments.

(There're Debian and Ubuntu packages, too. [And some screenshots and explanations on `makeuseof.com`](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/add-custom-functionality-to-nautilus-linux/))

For KDE4, i.e. Dolphin, there's something quite similar already integrated, **"Service Menus"** (via [`.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)) in `~/.kde/share/kde4/services/` (or whatever `kde4-config --path services` returns).

[Lots of ready-made service menus are on `kde-apps.org`](http://kde-apps.org/?xcontentmode=287).